# How can I get Chrome's automated tabs grouping feature to create all possible groups at once?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Here is Chrome's automated tabs grouping feature:

[image: How]

By default, I need to click on "create group" for the feature to create one group.

How can I get Chrome's automated tabs grouping feature to create all possible groups at once?

I use Chrome on Windows.